# What is the difference between these 2 HTTP Get definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am using Node.js Restify.

What is the difference between these 2 ways of defining HTTP Get requests on the server side? How will it affect the client URL calling the GET APIs and retrieving the URL parameters?

First one.

```
server.get('/echo', function (req, res, next) 
{
}
```

Second one.

```
server.get('/echo/:message', function (req, res, next)
{
}
```

Comment: The first one gets no parameter, the second one has a `message` parameter ?

Comment: What is the actual question? The parameter?

Comment: If only there were something one could refer to, some kind of [documentation](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#routing) or something...

Comment: THe question is ... How will it affect the client calling the GET APIs? What URL should the client be using?

Comment: the extra `:message` to url seems to be `socket path`. I am not sure though.

Comment: May I ask why the 2 negative votes? Please explain so that I can ask better questions in future. Thanks.

Comment: `What URL should the client be using? ` - the one appropriate for the situation

Comment: @user3293156 don't care about the downvotes. it is just 2 users out of 21 users (21 views).

Comment: The question got downvoted for the reasons the downvote button shows you when you hover it: It's unclear, and it demonstrates no research effort. If you read the Restify documentation and look at its examples, it's quite clear what the `:message` means in the route definition and how that would affect what the client would use when calling the endpoint. So if, having read the documentation and followed the examples, you have a specific question about how `:message` is determined or specified or some such, ask that question, with details about what you don't understand.

Comment: More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: T.J. Crowder, thanks. That is a good explanation. Upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a simple route that accepts requests using the "/echo" or "/echo/" path.

The second has a named parameter. Meaning you can access the passed value from request using "/echo/xxx" path via

```
req.params.message
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a good answer.